# MongoDB update nested objects in array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am stuck at this issue since three days. I need to update nested objects in Array. To make it more complex my Array is itself nested in object where key is to be created dynamically when ever user adds more category. I am stuck with two problems:

1. How to create category dynamically in queries?(passing value by reference is giving me a syntax error)
2. How to update a specific Array item based on some filters

[My Document in Mongodb which is to be updated.Object keys internet and electricity has to be dynamically created](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lj0fW.png)

For problem A I have resorted to hardcode the category and move on

```
    switch (category) {
                case 'internet':
                    qry = User.findOneAndUpdate({username: obj.username}, {$push: {"data.internet": newBill}});
                    break;
                case 'electricity':
                    qry = User.findOneAndUpdate({username: obj.username,}, {$push: {"data.electricity": newBill}});
                    break;
                case 'water':
                    qry = User.findOneAndUpdate({username: obj.username}, {$push: {"data.water": newBill}});
                    break;
                case 'gas':
                    qry = User.findOneAndUpdate({username: obj.username}, {$push: {"data.gas": newBill}});
                    break;
                default:

                    break;
            }
```

After the category is created I dont want the objects to be duplicate within, so I use DAY & Year as id to match with the intention to overwrite if a duplicate value is inserted. I have tried multiple ways to update but none is working. Please advice, a mongoDb expert needed

```
console.log("duplicate qry")
            switch (category) {
                case 'internet':
                    qry = User.findOneAndUpdate({username: obj.username}, {$push: {"data.internet": newBill,$position: index}});
                    break;
                case 'electricity':
                    qry = User.updateOne({username: obj.username, month:newBill.month, year:newBill.year}, {$set: {"data.electricity.$": newBill}});
                    console.log("Inside db case "+index)
                    break;
                case 'water':
                    qry = User.findOneAndUpdate({username: obj.username}, {$push: {"data.water": newBill,$position: index}});
                    break;
                case 'gas':
                    qry = User.findOneAndUpdate({username: obj.username}, {$push: {"data.gas": newBill,$position: index}});
                    break;
                default:

                    break;
            }
        }
```

My handler using two queries to findandupdate if no duplicate object is present. If present it returns index of the duplicate object which i can utilize for my second qry

```
//insert & update data
app.post('/update', function (req, res) {
    let obj = req.body
    let category = obj.category
    let insertObj = obj.data
    let flag = false;
    let index = 0;
    db.getUserDoc(req.body).then(function (data) {
        // console.log(data.doc)
        let keys = Object.keys(data.doc)
        console.log(`${category}`)
        if (keys.includes(`${category}`)) {
            let catObj = data.doc[`${category}`]
            let nestedKeys = Object.keys(catObj);
            let nestedVals = Object.values(catObj)
            for (let i = 0; i < catObj.length; i++) {
                if (catObj[i].month === insertObj.month && catObj[i].year === insertObj.year) {
                    console.log("not unique " + i)
                    flag = true;
                    index = i;
                    console.log(catObj.length);
                }
            }
            // console.log(insertObj.month + " "+ insertObj.year)
            console.log(catObj.length);
        }
        db.update(req.body, obj.data, obj.category, flag, index).then(function (data) {
            // res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
            // res.end(data)
            console.log(data);
            res.end(JSON.stringify(200));
        }).catch(function (e) {
            return res.status(500, {
                error: e
            })
        });

        // console.log(typeof data)
        // console.log(data);
        // res.end(JSON.stringify(data.doc));
    })


})
```

Comment: The line which is not working is this one "User.updateOne({username: obj.username, month:newBill.month, year:newBill.year}" ? Are you sure that an object match the values ? Did a findOne return the correct object ?

Comment: findOneAndupdate is working with $push, the problem is, it simply adds object in the array. So if i post a duplicate object it adds it as well. So i used two qry one to find the matching document and look for any similar objects matching DAY and Year in that category. From the response i filter out the index of the object

Comment: @Daphoque I have updated my question for more clarity